# Извлечь числа из введённой пользователем строки

Tags: python

По моей задумке человек должен написать команду `сРандом 5 20`.

Как вытащить эти два числа?

```
elif message == 'сРандом {} {}':

    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": , "random_id": 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

в лоб вытащить

```
text = input('введите команду и параметры через пробел:').split()

if text[0] == "срандом":
    values = list(map(int, text[1:]))
    res = random.randint(values[0], values[1]) 
    print(res)
```